# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encodePacked' when calling a smart contract function with web3.py

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging, web3.py, python

**Here is the pycharm code:**

```
import json

from web3 import Web3

ganache_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:7545'

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]

deployed_contract_address = 'contract address is typed here in my version'

abi = json.loads('[{"inputs": [{"internalType": "string","name": "Hello","type": "string"},{"internalType": "string","name": "World","type": "string"}],"name": "concatenate","outputs": [{"internalType": "string","name": "","type": "string"}],"stateMutability": "pure","type": "function"}]')

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=deployed_contract_address, abi=abi)

message = contract.functions.concatenate().call()

print(message)
```

But instead of printing the hello world as I thought it should, it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/[name]/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    message = contract.functions.abi.encodePacked().call()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encodePacked'
```

Here is the solidity code that has been deployed in remix:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0;

contract HelloWorld {

function concatenate(
        string calldata Hello,
        string calldata World)
        external 
        pure
        returns(string memory) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(Hello, World));
        }
}
```

Am I calling the function concatenate incorrectly in pycharm? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks...